# C++ - fastest sorting algorithm for objects based on distance

Tags: c++, sorting

I'm trying to make a game or 3D application using openGL. The game/program will have many objects in them and drawn to the screen(around 7000 of them). When I render them, I would need to calculate the distance between the camera and the object and sort them in order to correctly render the objects within the scene. Knowing this, what is the best way to sort them? I really want the sorting to be done really fast, but I've heard there are "trade off" for them, so what algorithm should I use to get the best performance out of it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: a lot of people are talking about the z-buffer/depth buffer. This doesn't work in some cases like a few people talked about. This is why I asked this question.

Comment: You do know that you don't need to sort the objects, you can just use depth buffering, right?

Comment: Depth buffering doesn't work in some cases, like when using transparent textures. In that case I believe you do have to sort your primitives to obtain correct rendering.

Comment: and you want to draw front objects first to fill the depth buffer fast (when there is no transparency)

Comment: I thought it's openGL's job to render the scene and make the z-ordering, why are you doing it ?

Comment: A BSP tree can be used to traverse the objects in depth order in linear time.

Comment: are those moving or inmovable objects or both?

Comment: @nneonneo I always wondered about that, and I think you're probably right. Although in that case, you can end up with some pretty horrific cases anyway. (c.f. http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Transparency_Sorting#Depth_Sorting)

Comment: Sorting 7000 items with the C++ library quicksort will be quite fast and very easy to code.  Try it before you go to something more complex.

Comment: @Xymostech: usual solution in that case is to make sure you subdivide your polys enough that pathological behaviour isn't obvious :) (Also, try to avoid using transparent textures as much as possible)

Comment: @Xymostech There are valid cases for sorting objects. For opaque objects it's best to render front to back so fragment shader doesn't waste cycles if the object is covered by another one. Transparent objects need to be rendered last in order back to front so your transparent object doesn't occlude objects behind it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sorting by distance doesn't solve the transparency problem perfectly. Consider the situation where two transparent surfaces intersect and each has a part which is closer to you. Perhaps rare in games, but still something to consider if you don't want an occasional glitched look to your renderer.

The better solution is order-independent transparency. With the latest graphics hardware supporting atomic operations, you can use an A-buffer to do this with little memory overhead and in a single pass so it is pretty efficient. See for example [this article](http://blog.icare3d.org/2010/07/opengl-40-abuffer-v20-linked-lists-of.html).

The issue of sorting your scene is still a valid one, though, even if it isn't for transparency -- it is still useful to sort opaque objects front to back to to allow depth testing to discard unseen fragments. For this, Vaughn provided the great solution of BSP trees -- these have been used for this purpose for as long as 3D games have been around.

Comment: Cool, I didn't knew about order independent transparency... but it isn't possible in OpenGL ES, right?

Comment: Hmmm... Correct me if I'm wrong, but I thought recursion methods/functions (BSP trees)are slower compared to iteration?

Comment: @Danny, you don't implement BSP trees with recursive calls. It's more natural to *analyse* them as recursive methods, but you don't actually implement them with recursive calls, you use iterations.

Answer (score 1):

Use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort which has O(n) complexity for nearly sorted arrrays.

In your case by exploiting temporal cohesion insertion sort gives fastest results.
It is used for http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweep_and_prune

From link above:

> In many applications, the configuration of physical bodies from one time step to the next changes very little. Many of the objects may not move at all. Algorithms have been designed so that the calculations done in a preceding time step can be reused in the current time step, resulting in faster completion of the calculation.

So in such cases insertion sort is best(or similar sorts with O(n) at best case)

Comment: ...and O(n^2) complexity for not-so-nearly-sorted arrays.

Comment: except from first frame you will always get an almost sorted array  because of temporal coherance. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collision_detection#Exploiting_temporal_coherence